# Django Restrict the Parent Foreign key to be set as Itself

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django, I am trying to create a project where a WBS can have other WBS as their parent. My Problem is that when I open the form for edit, I want to simply not display the self in the WBS drop-down so that it can't be set as self parent to avoid strange recursive relationship.

```
     def validate_not_self(value):
    if value and value == value.parent_wbs:
    raise ValidationError("A WBS cannot be its own parent.")


class WBS(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent_wbs = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='child_wbs',
                                   validators=[validate_not_self])
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  # This field will be automatically updated on each save
    modified_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)  # You can specify your own logic for updating this field

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention Model name as String.

Sample Code:

```
class WBS(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent_wbs = models.ForeignKey('WBS', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='child_wbs', validators=[validate_not_self])
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  # This field will be automatically updated on each save
    modified_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)  # You can specify your own logic for updating this field

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```